# Applescript error -25211 when executing script

Tags: applescript

I am receiving the following error when running a script using Apple Script Editor to automate my Cisco AnyConnect login.

Error: "System Events got an error: anyconnect is not allowed assistive access. (-25211)"

The options I am presented with are Edit or OK. OK ends the script, Edit allows me to Run the script from the Script Editor which is successful.

I have saved this script as a .app file to run it from Launchpad

Script:

```
tell application "Cisco AnyConnect"
    activate
end tell
repeat until application "Cisco AnyConnect" is running
    delay 1
end repeat
tell application "System Events"
    repeat until (window 1 of process "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client" exists)
        delay 1
    end repeat
    tell process "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client"
        keystroke ("**access URL**" as string)
        keystroke return
    end tell
    repeat until (window 2 of process "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client" exists)
        delay 1
    end repeat
    tell process "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client"
        keystroke ("**the password is entered here**" as string)
        keystroke return
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script file that you saved as an .app needs to be added to the list of applications that are allowed to control your computer.  Also add the Cisco AnyConnect app and ScriptEditor.app to the list of applications that are allowed.

[image]

Comment: awesome, that fixed it. Thanks

Comment: @ArtMazza  I would appreciate you marking my post with a +1 and accepted answer.. Just saying  :-)